# How to make two backbone fetch calls and combine it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backbone.js

I need to call two back end calls on the same collection and merge the results it to single collection object. Also I need to trigger 'sync' method only once both of the fetch methods are success.

Here is the code snippet

```
myCollection.fetch({ headers: {myheader: 'test1'}, data: {status: 'test1'}, reset: true});
myCollection.fetch({ headers: {myheader: 'test2'}, data: {status: 'test2'}, reset: true, add: true});

myCollection.once('sync error', function () {
    $('#js-my-grid').html(view.render().el);

});
```

I need to render the view only once both of the fetch are completed. How is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to use the `reset` parameter? I haven't tested it, but I believe that will make it so whichever response comes in last will be what is in the collection. They won't be merged together. Is that what you expect or should these be happening serially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) if it is ok that it renders the view as soon as one of them fails:

```
$.when(myCollection.fetch({ headers: {myheader: 'test1'}, data: {status: 'test1'}, reset: true}),
       myCollection.fetch({ headers: {myheader: 'test2'}, data: {status: 'test2'}, reset: true, add: true}))
 .always(function() {
     $('#js-my-grid').html(view.render().el);
 });
```

If you use `.done` you can assign a callback that will be executed when both are successful and if you use `.fail` you can define a callback that will be executed if either of the requests fail. I used `.always` since it looks like you were wanting to render the view whether the requests were successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;

myCollection.fetch({..., success: _internal});
myCollection.fetch({..., success: _internal});

function _internal() {
    count ++;
    if (count < 2) return;
    //2 calls are finished. do whatever you want here.
}
```

Comment: As @rdubya mentioed if you want to merge 2 collections result into single collection there is no need for `reset: true`